# Android app startup wizard

Tags: android

I'm looking to figure out a solution for helping a user enter some configuration data during the first time it's executed.  I have a main activity that shows a list of photos in a grid.

During the onCreate method for the main activity, if I find that a user has not configured the app before, I switch to a series of two activities.  The user fills out the required data in those two activities (think wizard-style, one after another).  Once they have entered data on the second activity, they are shown the original main activity.

Is this a standard, or preferred way to do things?  I couldn't find an easier way to do this, or a built-in way.

Instead of using onCreate, is there a way to programatically choose the first activity based on whether it's the first time the app has been run or not?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code for this problem

```
if( getSharedPreferences("FirstTime", 0).getBoolean("check", true))
             {
                getSharedPreferences("FirstTime", 0) .edit().putBoolean("check", false);
                /////////Write First Time code
             }
            else
            {
                /////Write Second Time code
            }
```